# Исполнение C# приложений без .Net Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть приложение и несколько необходимых DLL к нему, и это приложение необходимо запускать на машинах, на которых нет возможности установить .Net Framework, как сделать это?

Слышал про Turbo Studio, но не понял, как это реализовать, ибо нормальных гайдов нет, помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Желательно иметь возможность запускать приложения на Windows XP и выше.

Comment: Почему нет возможности установить .Net Framework ?

Comment: А почему бы не купить компьютеры нормальной мощности и не поставить на них Windows 10?

Comment: Почему бы вообще не писать на С++. XD

Comment: Тогда запускай виртуальную машину с XP! Настроишь там все что хочешь)

Comment: А если необходимые для запуска базовые библиотеки Net framework скопировать в папку с приложением? Насколько я знаю, net framework это не java машина, это именно набор библиотек и приложения запускаются вполне самостоятельно. Но это не точно

Comment: Наверное, вы можете установить [`mono`](http://www.mono-project.com/download/)

Comment: Покурите "mono aot" вроде он stand alone умеет

Comment: И еще если приложение консольное можно попробовать net core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разрабатывайте на другой платформе, например *mono*.

Иначе - никак, без *.NET* не получится запустить.

Если хотите поддерживать XP, используйте .NET v4, так как для XP реализована поддержка не выше 4 версии фреймворка.

Для решения проблемы можно в *setup* включить *.NET Client framework*, который весит 27 мб, и содержит только те библиотеки, которые нужны для запуска. **[Гайд](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework)**

Comment: mono умеет wpf?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вместо WPF можно использовать Avalonia UI

Comment: @PavelMayorov, уже можно?

Comment: @АндрейNOP что значит "уже"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, проект уже на столько зрелый, что можно безболезненно пользоваться?

Answer (score 2):

Это технически возможно. Вы можете создать Seft-Contained приложение .NET Core. Но для GUI надо будет использовать библиотеку, которая не зависит от .NET. Например, UWP или какое-то третьестороннее решение.